# Error while editing grid view record

Tags: c#-4.0, c#-3.0

I got following error while i am clicked edit button on grid view for 2 page

```
    System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection.
Parameter name: index
```

can you please specify what should i have to do to remove this error

following is the code for edit command, It works well when i am on first page but gives erro if i goes to another any page in grid view

```
protected void GVviewReminder_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
    {
        lblError.Text = "";
        if (e.CommandName == "Edit")
        {
            GridViewRow selectedRow = GVviewReminder.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)];

            string ID = selectedRow.Cells[1].Text;

            Response.Redirect("edit_health_reminder.aspx?HealthReminderIsOpen=true&id=" + ID);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error log says index out of range so look at collections.

```
GVviewReminder.Rows[Convert.ToInt32(e.CommandArgument)]

selectedRow.Cells[1].Text
```